# mysql_fetch_row returns value above zero despite actually being zero

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running the following query but `$new` returns `0`:

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM flagged WHERE status=0") or die(mysql_error()); 
$new = mysql_fetch_row($count);

if ($new != 0) {
            echo "<script language=\"javascript\">$.titleAlert(\"New Logs - ($new[0])\");</script>";
        }
```

Problem is the if-condition keeps getting met when it shouldn't when `$new != 0`

I even tried:

```
if ($new > 0) {
//update title about new logs
}
```

Either way, the title is still updated and I'm not sure why.

> New Logs - (0)

Comment: post the mysql error if you get one

Comment: `array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do

```
var_dump($new);
```

and you'll see why your `if` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean. `$new` should be an array not a scalar value per the PHP documentation.

[mysql_fetch_row documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Answer (score 1):

this code

```
$new = mysql_fetch_row($count);
```

makes $new becomes an array

try to compare it like this:

```
if ($new[0] != 0)
```

or even better, so You would be 100% sure it's what You need.

```
if (count($new) == 1 && intval($new[0]) != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_row` should return an array or `FALSE`.

Maybe adjust your conditional to:

```
if ( !$new ) {
    // some code here
}
```